# Getting out_of_range error when running my code

Tags: c++

We have to write this code for class, but I am getting an out-of-range error from the part of code below. It is supposed to be like a simon-says thing, where the letter you have to type in is the same. The exact error I'm getting is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
Abort (core dumped).
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>                     // for I/O
#include <cstring>                      // for strlen()
#include <cstdlib>                      // for random numbers
#include <unistd.h>                     // for sleep()
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS = 15;
    int       numRounds = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS;

    // if a command line argument is given, use that string to init the
    // "random" sequence and set the number of rounds to play the game
    if (argc == 2) {
        numRounds = strlen(argv[1]);
    }

    string    s;                         // A string used to pause the game
    char     *seq = new char[numRounds]; // Sequence of numRounds colors to match
    char      colors[] = "RGBY";         // Allowable colors
    bool      lost = false;              // Indicates whether we win or lose
    int       round;                     // Indicates the current round

    // Initialize random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    // Determine the random color sequence using either argv[1] or
    // randomly determined letters from 'R', 'G', 'B', and 'Y'
    for (int j = 0; j < numRounds; j++) {
        seq[j] = (argc == 2) ? argv[1][j] : colors[rand() % 4];
    }

    // Wait until the player is ready
    cout << "Welcome to Simon, press enter to play .... ";
    getline(cin, s, '\n');


    //code
    string input;
    cout << flush;
    int I;
    round = 1;
    while(!lost){
        for(i = 0 ; i < round; i++){
            cout << "Simon says: " << seq[i] << flush;
            sleep(1);
            cout << "\010." << flush << endl;
        }

        cout << "Please enter " << round << " characters to match ";
        cin >> input;

        if (numRounds <= round){
            cout << "you won" << endl;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < round; i++);{
            if(input.at(i) != seq[i]){
                lost = true;
            }
        }

        cout << "you lost" << endl;
        cout << "the correct sequence was ";
        for(int i = 0; i < round; i++){
            cout << seq[I];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line do you get out of range?  Maybe you want to make sure that the user entered the proper number of characters? `if(input.at(i) != seq[i]){` would throw this error if i was greater than or equal to `input.length()` and that would happen if the user entered less than round characters.

Comment: `int I;` at the top does't initialize `I`. When that value is used later, in `cout << seq[I]`, it still hasn't been assigned a value. So the result is nonsense.

Comment: And it this case, that nonsense result appears to be a kinder-than-average tool chain reporting an out of range error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am getting an out-of-range error" Well, did you try to figure out what indexes are being attempted? Did you try to figure out what indexes are valid? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/). The problem that was pointed out here is a simple typo, which makes the question off topic for Stack Overflow. You are expected to try to look for these things before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you have a `std::string` whose `size()` is 1 character, and you are trying to use its `at()` method to access a character at an index which is `>= 1`, which is out of bounds.

One problem I see is that this loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < round; i++);{
                          ^
```

Has an erroneous `;` that causes the loop to do nothing but increment `i` until it reaches `round`, thus `i` is **always** equal to `round` in the subsequent expression `if(input.at(i) != seq[i])`. And `at()` performs bounds-checking, so will throw `std::out_of_range` if `i >= input.size()` is true.

After removing that erroneous semicolon, so the loop body is actually using `i` the way you intended, there is another problem.  `i` is being used as an index into `input` and `seq`, however the lengths of `input` and `seq` are not guaranteed to be equal. Even though you are asking the user to enter `round` number of characters for `input`, you are not *enforcing* that.

The `input.at(i)` expression is the *only* expression in the whole program that is performing bounds-checking, and thus must be where the `std::out_of_range` error is being thrown from.

Also, you are never incrementing `round`. And, there is some logic in your `while` loop that should be moved after the loop has exited.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>                     // for I/O
#include <cstring>                      // for strlen()
#include <cstdlib>                      // for random numbers
#include <limits>                       // for numeric_limits
#include <unistd.h>                     // for sleep()
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS = 15;
    int       numRounds = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS;

    // if a command line argument is given, use that string to init the
    // "random" sequence and set the number of rounds to play the game
    if (argc == 2) {
        numRounds = strlen(argv[1]);
    }

    string    seq(numRounds, '\0');      // Sequence of numRounds colors to match
    char      colors[] = "RGBY";         // Allowable colors
    bool      lost = false;              // Indicates whether we win or lose
    int       round = 1;                 // Indicates the current round

    // Initialize random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    // Determine the random color sequence using either argv[1] or
    // randomly determined letters from 'R', 'G', 'B', and 'Y'
    for (int j = 0; j < numRounds; ++j) {
        seq[j] = (argc == 2) ? argv[1][j] : colors[rand() % 4];
    }

    // Wait until the player is ready
    cout << "Welcome to Simon, press enter to play .... ";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    //code
    string input;
    while (round <= numRounds){
        for(int i = 0; i < round; ++i){
            cout << "Simon says: " << seq[i] << flush;
            sleep(1);
            cout << "\b." << flush << endl;
        }

        do {
            cout << "Please enter " << round << " character(s) to match: ";
            cin >> input;
        }
        while (input.size() != round);

        for(int i = 0; i < round; ++i){
            if (input[i] != seq[i]){
                lost = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* alternatively:
        lost = (input.compare(0, round, seq, round) != 0);
        */

        if (lost)
            break;

        ++round;
    }

    if (lost){
        cout << "you lost" << endl;
        cout << "the correct sequence was ";
        for(int i = 0; i < round; ++i){
            cout << seq[i];
        }
        /* alternatively:
        cout.write(seq, round);
        */
    }
    else {
        cout << "you won" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```